# Need to change SQL query in android studio database to return multiple results

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a functioning database within my android app that returns one result queries.  I am trying to return multiple results for a Wine keyword but every time I try the app crashes when i run it.  I am fairly new to android coding so I could be missing something obvious.

The first .java is the search function.  The second one is the query activity.

```
package com.example.winedatabase;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseAccess {
    private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static DatabaseAccess instance;
    Cursor c = null;

    //private constructor so that object creation from outside is avoided
    private DatabaseAccess(Context context){
        this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);

    }

    //to return the single instance of database
    public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context){
        if(instance == null){
            instance= new DatabaseAccess(context);

        }
        return instance;
    }

    //to open the database
    public void open(){
        this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    //closing the database connection
    public void close(){
        if (db != null) {
            this.db.close();
        }
    }
    //method to query and return the result from the database
    public String getKeyword(String winename){
        c = db.rawQuery(" select WineName from Wine where WineName LIKE %'"+winename+"'%", new String[]{});
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while(c.moveToNext()){
            String description = c.getString(0);
            buffer.append(""+description);
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

}
```

```
package com.example.winedatabase;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class KeywordSearch extends AppCompatActivity {

    public EditText name;
    public Button query_button;
    public TextView result_address;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_keyword_search);

        name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        query_button = findViewById(R.id.query_button);
        result_address = findViewById(R.id.result);

        //set onClickListnener to query button

        query_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //create the instance of database access class and open database connection

                DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                databaseAccess.open();

                //get string value of edittext

                String n = name.getText().toString();
                String description = databaseAccess.getKeyword(n);  //used the get address method to get address

                //set text to result field
                result_address.setText(description);
                databaseAccess.close();
                //database connection closed

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is syntactically wrong. The wildcard `%` and the parameter `winename` should be enclosed inside single quotes, but also it is recommended and safer to pass the parameter `winename` in the 2nd argument of `rawQuery()`.
Change to this:

```
c = db.rawQuery(
    "select WineName from Wine where WineName LIKE '%' || ? || '%'", 
    new String[]{winename}
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This fixed it completely.  I know you already answered my question but would you mind explaining more about where to use the double and single quotes or why I don't need winename within the query itself?  My sql knowledge is shaky at best.

Comment: You should use single quotes to enclose string literals. For example: `select Winename from Wine where WineName = 'Beringer'`. But when you have the value (`'Beringer'`) in a variable it is safer to use `?` placholders and pass it in the string array which is the 2nd argument of rawQuery() so you avoid the risk of sql injection (find more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). The double quotes can be used to enclose identifiers like table and column names, but they are also acceptable for string literals, so I prefer to use backticks or square brackets to avoid confusion.